# Concatenate two properties for a selectlist dropdown box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am returning some data from the database for a dropdown box.
I have two properties Province and ProvinceDesc that I will like to concatenate.

I kept getting an error while i did the concatenation for the model.LocationCodeList below.

How do I concatenate this?

```
        IList<ProfilesModel> objPrv = null;
        objProvince = _jobApplication.GetProvinceInformation(country,jobType);
        model.LocationCodeList = new SelectList(objPrv, "Province", "Province + '-' + ProvinceDesc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymouse class then bind it to your SelectList:

```
../
.Select(s => new 
     { 
       .../
       ProvinceText = string.Format("{0}-{1}", s.Province, s.ProvinceDesc) 
     });
model.LocationCodeList = new SelectList(objPrv, "Province", 'ProvinceText');
```

Comment: Thanks. will I do this after this statement  objProvince = _jobApplication.GetProvinceInformation(country,jobType); ?

Comment: Again, what is ProvinceText? where will i declare that?

Comment: It has been declared in anonymous class, you don't need to declare it.

Comment: `objPrv.ToList().Select(...`